# disable sign up with signInWithPhoneNumber in fireabase

Tags: firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication

I just use two methods on my web app.

1. SignInWithEmail
2. SignInWithPhoneNumber

And I want users can sign up with user&password which is possible now and then I get their phone number. So they can sing in with the phone number for the next time. But if someone put an unexcited phone number in sign in page it didn't show an error to say that phone number doesn't exist. And firebase just signed up that phone number!

I just want users could sign up for email and password!

Answer (score 0):

SignInWithPhoneNumber method will automatically sign up a new user if user doesn't exist. You can check if the returned user is a new user and if it's new, delete and sign out the user manually.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth provides the tools needed for building this. As Ti pointed it out, Firebase Auth returns `isNewUser` in `firebase.auth.UserCredential` returned on sign in/sign up. You can inspect that to tell if a phone number user is existing or new and wire your logic from there. You also have the ability to ask the user to provide their email/password afterwards. You can use `linkWithCredential` to link an email/password credential.